# Bundler: install gems from git to gems folder instead of bundler folder

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

The inside of your "Gem Path" (see: `$ bundle env`) contains a `gems` and a `bundler` folder. The `gems` folder is populated by gems installed e.g. via `gem install` or the `gem` tag of a `Gemfile`. The `bundler` folder, on the other hand, holds for example gems installed via the git feature of a Gemfile:

`gem 'my-gem', git: "https://github.com/x/y.git"`

I assume this is so that custom installations don't conflict with installations from a gem server. Nevertheless, I'd like to treat a specific gem installed from git as if it's coming from a gem server.

Is it possible in this case to tell `bundler` to use the `gems` folder instead?

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to clone the repo and then build and install the gem locally.

I've also looked at [`Gem::SpecificInstall`](https://github.com/rdp/specific_install) which might solve this issue (although not through bundler) but it doesn't support authentication for private repos which is a dealbreaker for me.